# Finding dictionaries which don't have forbidden key-value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following two lists:

```
List1 =
[
{"color":"red",
"size":"large"},

{"color":"blue",
"size":"medium"}
]

List2 =
[
{"color":"red",
"size":"large"},

{"color":"blue",
"size":"medium"},

{"color":"yellow",
"size":"small"}
]
```

What I need is a third list which only contains the difference between List1 and List2, comparing only the "color" keys instead of the whole dictionary. For example, given the above two lists, I'd expect something like:

```
List3 =
[
    {"color":"yellow",
    "size":"small"}
]
```

I have a function that returns a list of dictionaries. These dictionaries contain information on devices currently connected to a network.

I need a list of devices that have connected to the network since the last time checked, using the MAC address of the devices.

The reason I can't compare the whole dicts is because they have a variable inside them that ALWAYS changes.

Comment: It's not easy to do this as comparing `dict`s with each other is difficult. Do each of them contain specific keys that you already know, or is this for a generic list of them?

Comment: Would this be possible to convert your lists in real dict, or you can have duplicates in «colors» inside one of each list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use pandas module:

```
import pandas as pd

List1 =[{"color":"red","size":"large"},
        {"color":"blue","size":"medium"},
        {"color":"black","size":"medium"}]

List2 =[{"color":"red","size":"small"},
        {"color":"blue","size":"medium"},
        {"color":"yellow","size":"small"}]

List3 = pd.DataFrame(List1+List2).drop_duplicates('color', False).to_dict('records')
'''
[{'color': 'black', 'size': 'medium'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'size': 'small'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

For the data you presented, you could create a set of keys to compare in each list and compare the resulting sets with `symmetric_difference`.

```py
compare = 'color'
colors1 = {d.get(compare) for d in List1}
colors2 = {d.get(compare) for d in List2}

# {'yellow'}
difference = colors1.symmetric_difference(colors2)

# [{'color': 'yellow', 'size': 'small'}]
result = [d for d in List1 + List2 if d.get(compare) in difference]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a set of colors to avoid in the result using `functools.reduce()`, and then use a list comprehension to retain only the keys that do not have a color in that set:

```py
colors_to_avoid = reduce(lambda x, y: x | {y["color"]}, List1, set())
result = [item for item in List2 if item["color"] not in colors_to_avoid]

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
[{'color': 'yellow', 'size': 'small'}]
```

Comment: This produces an empty list if the `{'color': 'yellow', 'size': 'small'}` is in `List1` instead of `List2`

Comment: Is that expected behavior? OP said "difference" which I took to mean set difference as opposed to symmetric difference.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you’re right. I read it differently.